# the installation date of patches is different in control panel and microsoft updates session output in powershell

Tags: powershell, patch

I want to get the latest list of patches installed using powershell and could that using:

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$session.QueryHistory("",0,100) |select Date,Title
```

the output is :

```
 Date                 Title       
----                  --       
6/19/2020 5:27:58 AM  Cumulative Update..
6/10/2020 7:06:35 AM  Cumulative Update..
6/10/2020 7:04:37 AM  Security Update..
5/15/2020 6:24:37 AM  Cumulative Update..
```

where as if i check in control panel, the date is different, for example:

the date for KB KB4559309 is shown as 6/22/2020 instead of 6/19/2020
but for KB4560960 it is same as 6/10/2020.

so for some KB's it is showing same but for some, there is a difference. I want to know why the difference is there in the first place and how can i correct it?

I want the script to show the dates present in the control panel.

Thank you in advance.

Edit 1: output after converting to local time.

```
$session.QueryHistory("",0,100) | Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {([DateTime]($_.Date)).ToLocalTime()}} ,Title

#output
    Date                 Title       
    ----                  --       
    6/19/2020 10:57:58 AM  Cumulative Update..
    6/10/2020 12:36:35 AM  Cumulative Update..
    6/10/2020 12:34:37 AM  Security Update..
    5/15/2020 11:54:37 AM  Cumulative Update..
```

Edit 2:
I have tried an other approach to get the patches list. But even here, I am facing the same issue.

I have come across a log file which stores the entire patch information.C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\reportingevents.log But the problem is that this file keeps on updating and hence I couldnt file much information on it.

```
$patches = gwmi win32_quickfixengineering  | Where { $_.InstalledOn -le [datetime]($InstalledOn.InstalledOn) } | sort InstalledOn -Descending | select-object Description,HotfixId, InstalledOn 

$InstalledOn = gwmi Win32_Quickfixengineering   | select @{Name="InstalledOn";Expression={$_.InstalledOn -as [datetime]}} | Sort-Object -Property Installedon | select-object -property installedon -last 1
    $lastPatchDate = Get-Date $InstalledOn.InstalledOn -format dd-MM-yyyy
    #have also tried the get-hotfix but same problem followed.
    $patches = gwmi win32_quickfixengineering  | Where { $_.InstalledOn -le [datetime]($InstalledOn.InstalledOn) } | sort InstalledOn -Descending | select-object Description,HotfixId, InstalledOn
```

I have also tried converting the installedOn to local time but that did not help.The result is same in all the approaches and there are no multiple entries for a single KB.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it _may_ be caused by the KB having been updated. have you checked to see if the KB is listed more than once in the `Microsoft.Update.Session` listing?

Comment: yes i have checked and it is listed only once..

Comment: ah! then i am out of ideas. i will go back to lurking ... good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. There is no output from shared code snippet.

Comment: @JosefZ - made the necessary changes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The control panel is showing you the dates converted to your Local Timezone, whereas your code show the dates as-is, meaning UTC time.

Try

```
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$Searcher.QueryHistory(0,$historyCount) | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {([DateTime]($_.Date)).ToLocalTime()}} ,Title
```

Comment: Hi Theo. Have tried it but it still doesn't give the correct dates as mentioned in the control panel..There is an addition of 5 hours in the time but the date is still same. 
Thankyou

Comment: @Deeksha You're using the Update.Session object instead of the Searcher object to query the update history. I edited my answer to use `$Searcher` now. Also, I took off the empty string first parameter. The difference in dates you experience could come from (as @Lee_Dailey suggested) the fact that you are limiting the results to 100, where usually, you would use the `$Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()` for that.

Comment: Tried your updated answer as well but no luck. The output is same as before..